# activerecords 'create' is ignoring object property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently added a time_zone property to my User table and I'm trying to insert a time zone when I create the user... however, the property is being completely ignored

```
 user = User.create( :username => user[:username],
                        :name => user[:username],
                        :email => user[:email],
                        :time_zone => user[:time_zone],
                        :password => user[:password],
                        :password_confirmation => user[:password])
```

I check the log and the insert statement generated includes everything except the time_zone... why?

Could it be because the time_zone has a default value? although this wouldn't make sense...

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the rails version, check if you have to white list it in strong_parameters.

Comment: @Mark how? It's weird I even tried using new instead of create and it just skips the property as if it didn't exist

Comment: It has just been an idea. I thought it might be a problem with strong_parameters. What's the version of rails you are using. Another thing that ringed my attention is that you wrote, that you added the property to the table. Has this been done with a migration or directly in the database? If direct Rails might not know about this field. What is the output of `User.new` does it include the `time_zone` field?

Comment: I have added it through a migration `add_column :users, :time_zone, :string` ... How do i check the output of User.new? @Mark Thanks man

Comment: Sound correct. You can start a rails console with the command `rails console` in this you can execute the command `User.new`. The output might look like this: `irb(main):001:0> User.new
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil, `

Comment: BTW: I am curious about the rails version, because you are using the old hash syntax

Comment: Rails 5.0 and ruby 2.2.3 ... can you suggest some new syntax? My rails console is giving a weird devise error @Mark

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132433/discussion-between-mark-and-walker).

Answer (score 1):

The create property was being ignored because what was being inserted was the same as the default value...

When I tested inserted a User record with a time_zone different than the default time_zone then it actually generated the insert statement with that new time_zone....

Didn't know rails was this good!